# How to return neighbouring items of an item in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following collection

```
var players = new[]{
     new {Id = 1, Name = "A", Score = 70},
     new {Id = 2, Name = "B", Score = 50},
     new {Id = 3, Name = "C", Score = 100},
     new {Id = 4, Name = "D", Score = 90}
 };
```

If I wanted to return the position of specific player (say, Player with ID = 1) in above list ordered by score I could write a query like this:

```
var result = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score)
             .Select((p, i) => new {player = p, Position = i})
             .Where(x => x.player.Id == 1)
             .First();
int position = result.Position;
var player = result.player;
```

Now how can I take this further and return the **neighbouring items** in addition to the actual player? Neighbouring items are the previous and next player and their respective positions when we order the list by score.

Here is the expected result of the query

```
var expectedResult = new[]{
    new {Id = 2, Name = "B", Score = 50},   //Previous player
    new {Id = 1, Name = "A", Score = 70},
    new {Id = 4, Name = "D", Score = 90}    //Next Player 
};
```

Could the above result be achieved by a single LINQ expression? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> GetOverlappingChunks<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int chunkSize)
{
    List<T> chunk = new List<T>(chunkSize);

    foreach (var elt in sequence)
    {
        chunk.Add(elt);

        if (chunk.Count > chunkSize)
            chunk.RemoveAt(0);

        if (chunk.Count == chunkSize)
            yield return chunk.ToArray();
    }
}

// ...

var result = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score)
             .GetOverlappingChunks(3)
             .Where(x => x[1].Id == 1);
```

(Too bad C# doesn't have a built-in deque type.)

If you need to handle cases where there are less than three players in the list, then you'd need to tweak `GetOverlappingChunks` and the check slightly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Zip operator defined in .NET 4.0, or use the Scan operator defined in the Rx extensions:

With zip:

```
var result = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score)
    .Select((p, i) => new {Player = p, Position = i})
    .ToList(); //forces evaluation

result.Zip(result.Skip(1), (i,j) => new {First= i, Second=j})
      .Zip(result.Skip(2), (i,j) => new {First = i.First, Second = i.Second, Third=j})
      .First(o => o.Second.player.Id == 1);
```

But this won't give you neighbors for the first and last player. If you want them too, you have to massage your collections (since all three ienumerable must have the same number of items)

Comment: You also need a rule for ties, since score isn't a total order.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The number of neighbours I want returned is set to 2 (one before and one after the item) just for simplicity reasons. In real life, I have potentially a very large list and I would like to return 50 neighbours and I can't see how your solution allows that.